# Firebase Dynamic Links - Is the click count right?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've been using Firebase Dynamic links and I'm starting to question the count accuracy.

I created a link and posted it to Twitter, Facebook, and LinkedIn. All the platforms reported no clicks, but when I get the link stats via the API:

```
linkEventStats: [

{ count: '12', event: 'CLICK', platform: 'OTHER' },

{ count: '12', event: 'REDIRECT', platform: 'OTHER' },

{ count: '2', event: 'CLICK', platform: 'IOS' },

{ count: '2', event: 'REDIRECT', platform: 'IOS' }

]
```

Perhaps the preview in Twitter or Facebook is counting toward the click? Has anyone had issues with the click count accuracy or have more insight into what counts as a click?

Comment: The preview sounds likely. It would certainly look the same to an end server, which can't tell if the get request came from a click event.

Comment: @kato You might be right. I wonder how bit.ly and other track, or don't track, impressions/previews.